# connection must be valid and open (executeScalar())

Tags: c#, mysql

Gives me this error `connection must be valid and open` I do not know how to solve it.

```
    private void loginUtenti(string user, string psw)
    {
        createConnection(); 
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=test;port=3306;password=******;"; ;
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        command = new MySqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Psw FROM Utenti WHERE Nome = '" + user + "';";
        object passwordInput = command.ExecuteScalar(); // error "connection must be valid and open" 
        string nullo = "";
```

---

Comment: `new ...` is not C. Please retag!

Comment: "HELP ME" also is not constructive, and please learn enough about stack overflow to properly format your code.

Comment: Assuming it's supposed to be [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

Try associating the command with the connection

```
    command.Connection = connection;
```

Also, what does 'createConnection' *do*?

**And use prepared statements/bind variables**. This is SQL injection wawiting to happen.

Comment: returns this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on that command

Comment: @user2489129 are you sure you have instantiated connection and opened it. Like this `Connection connection = new Connection(connectionString); connection.Open();`

Comment: It would appear that you will answer your question by answering mine first. Read carefully?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the intended connection to the Command object also open the same connection before executing the query  with cmd.ExecuteScalar()